# Quick - Get multiple BBCode links from imgur?

Tags: imgur

There used to be a way to get a copy-and-paste link of all the [img] codes from an album on imgur, did they remove that? If not, how do you get all the [img]s besides manually doing it?

Example;
[IMG]http://i.imgur.com/photohere.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

paste this in your console:

```
var bb=[];$('a.zoom').each(function(){bb.push('[img]'+this.href+'[/img]');});console.log(bb.join(''));
```

I'm sure someone could make a userscript out of this, but this is enough for me.

or, more elegant, if you don't want to select the text yourself:

```
var bb=[];$('a.zoom').each(function(){var h = this.href; bb.push('[url='+h+']'+'[img]'+h+'[/img][/url]');});window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter",bb.join('\n'));
```

This one opens a prompt with the text already selected, wraps each image in a link, and separates each [img] with a line return